# Android TextView getText() method

Tags: android-layout

Suppose I have declared a TextView username. and I have not assign any string to it by  **username.setText()** and before that if I called **username.getText()** method,  whats it going to return ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return `null` because nothing is in there. `.getText()` will return the text the TextView is displaying.

I would first check that the TextView username is not null like following:

```
if (username.getText() != null){
 //TextView not null
 //Do something
}
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I have a toast msg inside it  and even if username is empty   its displaying the toast msg